# Remove Higher level index in Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-level

I have a Dataframe as given Below,

```
      a
   ---+--
    b | c
--+---+--
0 | 1 | 2
1 | 3 | 4
```

All i wanted to do is remove the Higher level index 'a' from data frame and get the Result output as

```
   b | c
--+---+--
0 | 1 | 2
1 | 3 | 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index()
```